# Kernel density estimator that doesn't collapse in the tails

Tags: nonparametric, density-function, kernel-smoothing, smoothing

I have iid data-points $x_1, \dots, x_n$, generated by an unknown density $f(x)$.
So far I have approximated $f(x)$ with a normal $N(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma}^2 )$, where $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ are sample average and variance, but I would like something more flexible.

I have tried with simple Kernel density estimators, but the problem is that in my application I often need to evaluate the estimated density $\hat{f}(x)$ deep in the tails (say I need $\hat{f}(x)$ for $|x| >> 2\sigma$) and it looks like $\hat{f}(x)$ drops to zero very rapidly in the tails.

This image shows what I mean:

[image: Normal vs KDE for normal data]
Here is the R code:

```
# Generate normal data
N <- 10000
x <- rnorm(N)

# Calculate Bandwidth
tmp <- density(x, kernel = "gaussian")

# Evaluate the log-density
xSeq <- y <- seq(-5, 5, by = 0.1)

for(ii in 1:length(y))
y[ii] <- log(sum(dnorm(xSeq[ii]-x, 0, sd = tmp$bw))/N)

plot(xSeq, y, type = 'l', main = "Black = KDE, broken = normal (true)",
     ylab = "Log-density", xlab = "x")
lines(xSeq, dnorm(xSeq, log = TRUE), lty = 2)
```

In this case the true density is really Gaussian, but in my application it is unknown. Obviously estimating tail probabilities is very difficult, but what I would like is a KDE that doesn't drop to zero so fast. In the literature I found a lot about fat-tailed kernels, but I'm not sure whether that's what I need.
Thanks!

EDIT: One might ask "why do you need to evaluate the estimated density very far in the tails?". The answer is that I want to use this density to estimate a likelihood $f(x_0|\theta)$, where $x_0$ is an observation and $\theta$ is a unknown parameter. Given a set of parameters $\theta^0$ I simulate $n$ data-points $x_1,...,x_n$, estimate their density and use it to get an estimate of the likelihood $\hat{f}(x_0|\theta^0)$. Give that the real $\theta$ is unknown, when I initialize the algorithm at $\theta^0$ my sample can be very far from $x_0$ and hence I will evaluate the estimated density in the extreme tails.

Comment: what prior knowledge do you have about the support of the data? It seems like you know what the tails "should" be doing. Tell us more.

Comment: In general the support of the data is the real line, but don't have any particular distribution in mind. I'm not saying that the distribution of the data is heavy tailed, but I would prefer a density estimator that has heavy tails to one that has thin tails like the KDE I plotted. One reason is that I prefer having wider confidence intervals since they are more conservative. In the plot you see that the KDE density collapses suddenly around -4 and +4 and that's not nice because in my application I need to evaluate the density really deep in the tail (like $x = 10$ in this case).

Comment: You could try mixture of Gaussians to model your density.

Comment: I'd suggest considering a [logspline](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logspline/) density estimate

Answer (score 2):

##### It is a good idea to use the T-distribution to build a KDE

When you build a KDE, once you go outside the data range, the rate of decay in the tails is determined by the rate of decay in the tails of the kernel distribution.  The normal distribution has very thin tails (which decay at an exponentially-quadratic rate) so it is unsurprising that the tails of your KDE decay rapidly outside the data range.  If you want to ameliorate this, and allow fatter tails, I would recommend that you use a T-distribution as the kernel for your KDE.  This allows you to adjust the degrees-of-freedom parameter to adjust the desired "fatness" of the tails, and it even allows you to have heavy tails that give infinite variance in your KDE.

You can implement a KDE using the T-distribution using the `KDE` function in the [`utilities` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=utilities).  This function allows you to specify the degrees-of-freedom parameter to control the fatness of the tails of the KDE.  (This function produces an object containing probability functions for the KDE; you can also load those functions directly to the global environment so that you can call them just like the probability functions of another distribution.)  Here is an example of fitting a KDE using a T-distribution with two degrees-of-freedom, which means that the KDE has tails that are sufficiently heavy to give infinite variance.  If you were to examine the log-density of this KDE (using the `dkde` function generated here) you will see that the raite of decay in the tails is much slower than for a KDE that uses the normal kernel.

```
#Load the package
library(utilities)

#Generate some mock data
set.seed(1)
DATA <- rnorm(40)

#Create a KDE using the T-distribution with two degrees-of-freedom (infinite variance)
MY_KDE <- KDE(DATA, df = 2, to.environment = TRUE)
plot(MY_KDE)

#Show the KDE output
MY_KDE

  Kernel Density Estimator (KDE) 
 
  Computed from 40 data points in the input 'DATA'
  Estimated bandwidth = 0.367412  
  Input degrees-of-freedom = 2.000000  
 
  Probability functions for the KDE are the following: 
 
      Density function:                   dkde * 
      Distribution function:              pkde * 
      Quantile function:                  qkde * 
      Random generation function:         rkde * 
 
  * This function is presently loaded in the global environment
```

[image]

Comment: Since the target density is explicitly *unknown,* there is as little basis to propose a Cauchy kernel as there is to propose any other kernel.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a consequence of the way you have presented your example, but it looks like your density function has finite support (e.g, a truncated Gaussian)? If this is the case, why not use a spline density estimator with linear tails:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pendensity/vignettes/pendensity.pdf

You could also have a look into wavelet density estimation:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavethresh/wavethresh.pdf

I'm not sure about the suggestion of using a logspline? Surely this will have by construction exponential (fast decaying) tails?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually in my example the data is normal (in fact x <- rnorm(N)) so the real density has the real line as support. The KDE drops to zero so sharply because there are no sample points outside $x \in [-4,4]$.

Comment: Perhaps the 'application density' can be assumed to have finite support? 
You could also just estimate a variance and mean from your data and fit a Gaussian.

Comment: No, in general I can't assume that. The normal is what I was using and it is quite robust, but I was looking for something more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I have a number of questions.

Why do you care about the tail of the distribution if you don't know where it is?

You have said that you would need to evaluate the density at x = 10 in your example. How many samples do you have? For KDE I am fairly certain you don't have enough for this. Looking at that part of the tail, we have

$$P(|X| > 10) = erf(\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}})$$

and thus one sample in $\sim 6.5\times10^{22}$  will have $|x| \geq 10$ ([wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/%281-erf%2810/sqrt%282%29%29)). Which brings me back to the question of why you need to evaluate that far out on the tail.

Your tail density will also be significantly affected by the bandwidth that you select for your KDE. If you make your kernel have bandwidth = 1, I bet your graph will look a lot nicer at the tails, but this is only due to the coincidence of the kernel having the same tail properties as the density of interest.

Comment: Your question is very legitimate, so I have edited my question to add some information about my application. Regarding the number of samples I have: I control the sample size, so I can sample as much as I want, but the computational cost increases. In addition, as you have said, it might take forever before I get a sample in the far tails.